# Azure DevOps Post Deployment gates Kusto Query,

Tags: azure-devops, kusto-explorer

We are working on Migration in Azure Devops, Classic release pipeline to YAML. We completed all the steps except post deployment gates.

My classic editor has Kusto query post deployment approvals condition. We checked environment and there is no option for Kusto query post deployment gates. How can we done this, Please share your thoughts.

We already try with Time Delay task and try to excute query using powershell. But we have more than 80 stages, it's very difficult to control it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classic release pipeline, the checks (gates and approvals) are set and located on each stage, and each stage can support **Pre-deployment** and **Post-deployment** checks.

In YAML pipelines, the checks are set and located on each environment. The stages in YAML pipelines do not support **Post-deployment** checks. All the checks should be validated before the deployment gets started if the deployment targets to the environment.

The Kusto query gate (**`Azure Data Explorer Query`**) is from the extension "[**Azure Data Explorer - Pipeline Tools**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Azure-Kusto.PublishToADX)". This gate is only available for stages in classic release pipelines, and it is not for environments used in YAML pipelines.

If your projects really need that the environments can support the **`Azure Data Explorer Query`** gate, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). This will make it more convenient for the engineer teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

---